# siunitx: share the same value with two different units

Tags: siunitx, typography, best-practices

If I have two different constants share the same value at some condition, what is the better way to aesthetically present this information than typing the two units after each other?

For example, I need to show that I will symbolically substitute both `K_b` and `K_t` with `K` since they have the same value while indicating that `K` can take either unit of theirs.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx}
\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations, 
    inter-unit-product = {{\cdot}},
    per-mode = symbol,
    bracket-unit-denominator,
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\radpers}{\radian\s\tothe{-1}}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
    For ideal series DC motor, back-emf and torque constants are\\ $K_b = K_t = K = \SI{0.2}{\N\m\per\A}~\si[sticky-per]{\V\per\radpers}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the units are not the same, I would argue that these variables are *not* equal. Only the numerical value *for this choice of units* is equal, so your equation should reflect that. Personally, I would opt for dividing by the unit.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  per-mode = symbol,
}

\parindent 0pt

\begin{document}

For ideal series DC~motor, back-emf and torque constants are
\[
  \frac{K_{\mathrm{b}}}{\si{\newton\meter\per\ampere}}
  = \frac{K_{\mathrm{t}}}{\si{\volt\second\per\radian}}
  = \num{0.2}
  \eqqcolon K .
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

(In this specific example, the units are actually equal, so you could just say `K_{\mathrm{b}} = K_{\mathrm{t}} \eqqcolon K`. Note that in this case, `K` equals `0.2 V s`, while it is just `0.2` in the approach for *different* units above.)

Answer (score 2):

I would repeat the number also.

```latex
\begin{document}
    For ideal series DC motor, back-emf and torque constants are\\ $K_b = K_t = K = \SI{0.2}{\N\m\per\A} =\SI[sticky-per]{0.2}{\V\per\radpers}$
\end{document}
```